# Does naming properties with trailing double underscores have a meaning in C#?

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api, naming-conventions, double-underscore

The [`Thumbnail`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1YouTube_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1ThumbnailDetails.html) class of the YouTube v3 API has a member named [`Default__`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1YouTube_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1ThumbnailDetails.html#a1d47284a03fbb6ffdfdbf585536b1441) member. Its name has a double trailing underscore `__` at the end. Is this a naming convention? I haven't found any documentation about such rule.

On IRC, someone suggested that it could be generated code and that there was a mechanism to avoid keywords in the target language.

Is there a known and documented explanation about this?

Comment: _"Identifiers shouldn't contain two consecutive underscore (`_`) characters. Those names are reserved for compiler-generated identifiers."_ [C# identifier naming rules and conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names#naming-conventions) (bullet point #4)

Comment: @quaabaam, thanks. So it means it is generated or that the devs didn't follow the conventions?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand it.

Comment: @quaabaam, thanks, but sadly I don't understand your answer since I asked if it was generarated (by the compiler) **_or_** tif he devs didn't follow the conventions...

Comment: The 'YouTube v3 API' [ThumbnailDetails source](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/c33576fa44936241c301703658477f4565eda296/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.cs#L15108) on GitHub shows a utility was used to generate the code. It looks like the utility followed the convention, likely to avoid a conflict with the keyword in C#.  [comment indicating the code was generated](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/c33576fa44936241c301703658477f4565eda296/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.cs#L15)